# Convert dataframe into dictionary via the same values of the column

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe now and want to convert it into a dictionary based on the column `id`. I want to convert rows which `id` are 0 into two dictionaries of one list and do the same in rows which `id` is 1. Then combine these two lists into one list.

**Dataframe `df` :**

| id | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | x |
| 0 | b | x |
| 1 | a | y |
| 1 | a | x |

I've tried this before

```
new_dict = df.to_dict('record')
list_of_dict = list(new_dict)
final_list = list(list_of_dict)
```

and got an unexpected result which dictionaries didn't separated by `id`

```py
[ 
 [ 
  {Col1:"a",Col2:"x"},
  {Col1:"b",Col2:"x"},
  {Col1:"a",Col2:"y"},
  {Col1:"a",Col2:"x"}
 ]
]
```

Below is what I expect.

**List of list of dictionary:**

```py
[
 [
  {Col1:"a",Col2:"x"},
  {Col1:"b",Col2:"x"}
 ],
 [
  {Col1:"a",Col2:"y"},
  {Col1:"a",Col2:"x"}
 ]
]
```

*Actually, I was trying to fit the format of the feat of `sklearn_crfsuite.CRF().(feat,label)`.*

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. What have you tried based on your own research, and what went wrong woth your attempts? For example, group by, [to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) or [to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) seem like likely candidates

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is make a list of list of dictionaries.

Since you want to combine dictionaries with the same id into one list, we can use the groupby method.

```
# Group the dataframe by 'id'
grouped_df = df.groupby('id')

# Initialize an empty list to store the lists of dictionaries
final_list = []

# Iterate through the groups in the GroupBy object
for _, group in grouped_df:
    columns = group[["Col1", "Col2"]]
    
    # Convert the selected columns into a list of dictionaries using to_dict method
    list_of_dicts = columns.to_dict('records')
    
    # Append the list of dictionaries to the final_list
    final_list.append(list_of_dicts)
```

You can read more about different ways to use to_dict method here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html